# Exporting canvas to video

Tags: html, animation, canvas, export

Is it possible to export a canvas animation to video? I  would like to build a tool that would allow creating simple animations but then i would like to export them to .avi .mp4 or whatever video format.

Is this possible? If so, how can i do it?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar and so far I have not found anything satisfying for my needs, but here is one approach I would take for your needs: Send to your server as a collection of images (animated gif), use ffmpeg on the server to convert it to a video. Along the lines of ffmpeg -i animation.gif -s 420x300 animation.avi

Answer (score 8):

You could try to use a callback function to register a listener to the requestAnimationFrame and after each loop try to capture the canvas png file save it somewhere either server side or client side using some persistent method of html5 and use another software like ffmpeg later on to put them together to form a video file.

```
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
```

Code to get the canvas image/png info

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: that would create such a big data and possibly bring server or your own computer down. Try converting every frame of any video to jpgs/pngs...and you will see. isn't there any other way.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer this cannot bring down the server...

Comment: is it possible to export canvas in mp4 format from client side? or any other solution using javascript, jQuery or angular framework?

Answer (score 6):

Okay. I know I'm 7 years late, but: THERE IS NOW A LIBRARY THAT EXACTLY FITS YOUR NEEDS!

[Whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) encodes videos. It works pretty well (but will slow down your application if you also intend to view the canvas in real time).

This is pretty hard to do without external libraries and I do not recommend using your own library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a screen capturing software with a predefined area of the screen where the canvas is located.

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-screen-recording-softwares-for-creating-attractive-screencasts/

Comment: I think his intent is to create a webpage for people to make animations and save as a video file. @user986871 Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yup, my intention is this to be a service for creating simple animations. Not very usable if the user needs to record the screen after that.